# vb2010 combobox automatic change text from items

Tags: vb.net

I am using **vb2010** and I have a problem with combobox. My code below get the items from mysql database then add it to the combobox. When there is an item in combobox say for example "**NERISON**" when I input "**N**" in the combox and press tab, the combobox will automatically change the text to "**NERISON**" -what I don't want. I just want to leave it with "N" as text. How would I do that?

```
If Not e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
        txtprice.Text = ""
            With cmb_particular
                .Items.Clear()
                load_dbase() ' connects to database
                CNN.Open()
                runSql("select particular from particular where status=0 and particular like '%" & .Text & "%' order by particular") ' my function for queries
                While dr.Read
                    .Items.Add(dr("particular"))
                End While
                CNN.Close()
                .SelectionStart = cmb_particular.Text.Length
                .DroppedDown = True
            End With
        End If
```

Comment: remove the `.SelectionStart = cmb_particular.Text.Length`

Comment: thnks for the reply but this doenst solved.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `autofill` / `autocompelte is enabled` in the combobox?

For WPF, set the following:

`IsTextSearchEnabled = False`

For Forms:

`ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode = False`

Answer (score 0):

In your combobox properties be sure that AutoCompleteMode=None

@Nerison:
I 've added a comboBox in a form. I don't change anything. I check its properties:

```
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode=None
ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource=None
ComboBox1.DropDownStyle=DropDown
```

I add a datatable as datasource. Now I have the bahaviour that you want. I type "N" and it doesn't suggest or append anything.
Could you please check it again?